# Retrieving Month from DATE field in MY SQL

Tags: php, mysqli, phpunit, mysql

Iam using **DATE TYPE** to store Date of birth in MY Sql database, 
I need to retrieve Month 12 from the following date 2012-12-25

My field name is DOB and I know retrieving MONTH is, using the query **MONTH(dob)**

But my issue is i have a object and method **$user->dob** which displays the complete date of birth of specific user, but i need to display the MONTH only using $user->dob , how can i do it in my method and class ? some thing like **month($user->dob)**

Comment: date('n',strtotime($user->dob));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT dob, MONTH(dob) AS month_dob ...
```

which would give you (presumably) `$user->month_dob`.

The alternative is to use (inefficient) PHP-side date manipulation, e.g.:

```
$month = date('n', strtotime($user->dob));
```

Comment: + for providing both examples, but noting MySQL over PHP.

Comment: Marc ..Thanks for your feedback.. could u pls tell why second method is inefficient ?

Comment: extracting a month from a full date in mysql is a very simple/cheap operation. doing it in php requires php to do string->date(int)->string, plus a LOT of math for that initial string->date conversion. of course, you could use string operations and simply EXTRACT the month portion of a date string, but then you're probably not y10k compatible.

Comment: Jason - could u please explain more specific, what are you trying to express ?

Comment: Marc.. Ha Ha, Thanks that's informative, No guarantee that php and my sql will exist until Year 10,000 :)

Answer (score 1):

Use php date function
`$month = date('m', strtotime('2012-12-25'));`

in your case `$month = date('m', strtotime($user->dob));`